# Properties of invertible and diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

PLEASE: I am not looking for a full proof. I would like to figure this out on my own. I'd definitely be thankful for some properties/identities/nudges in the right direction.

I am trying to prove the following:

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional. $T,S$ are operators on $V$ such that $T$ is diagonalizable and $S$ is invertible.

Then $STS^{-1}$ is also diagonalizable.

The direct implications that I can spot off the bat are the following:

1. $\exists (v_{1},...,v_{n})$ a basis of $V$ such that each vector is a distinct eigenvalue.
2. $\exists A= \mathcal{M}(T)$ such that $A$ is diagonal for some basis of V.
3. $\exists B= \mathcal{M}(S)$ such that $B$ is upper triangular with all non-zero diagonal entries.
4. It appears that $BA$ will always result in an invertable matrix.

I have not been able to determine anything useful from the generic matrix $ABA^{-1}$. It appears that it is not upper or lower triangular in nature, and I can't seem to determine generically whether or not it is invertable or diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$, then $Sv$ is an eigenvector of $STS^{-1}$.

Comment: The missing link. It was omnomnomnom delicious.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to give a hint that does not reveal all:

Note that $T$ is diagonalisable **iff** there is some $V$ such that
$V^{-1} T V$ is diagonal.

Spoiler:

> $(SV)^{-1} ( S T S^{-1} ) S V = ?$